# How to align two divs that have different sizes horizontally

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">line one</div>
    <div id="right">line one<br/>line two</div>
</div>
```

How to make left div and right div align on the bottom line? Basically to expand left div so both have the same height.

I don't want to set height explicitly for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the height or min-height property for the parent divison in the CSS like following

```
min-height:50px;
```

You can also set the line-height for it so that `<br />` works the expected way

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with the `display: table-cell` property, but it has no support among browsers like IE7 and older. Here's how to do it, anyway.

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gAQtR/1/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is known as part of the ["One True Layout"](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight):

```
#block_1, #block_2 {
    padding-bottom: 32767px;
    margin-bottom: -32767px;
}
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then there is the `display: table` approach, but it isn't supported in IE below 8.

Apart from that google for "CSS columns float height" or any similar combination.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by two ways one is to set the equal minimum height of both divs

> line one  line one
> line two
>
> ## left { min-height:50px; }
>
> ## right { min-height:50px; }

========================================================================

Or You can do it by inserting the 
 tag giving it the style of of clear:both before the closing tag of parent div like

> line one
>   line one
> line two

Answer (score 0):

The link below will show you the code for your problem
http://jsfiddle.net/tashniamit/kVqpE/1/